# Mule 4 Anypoint Studio download file from external api

Tags: api, file, download, mule, external

I will need to create a flow in Anypoint to download a .gz file from an external API source(through OAuth). I have created a listener -> Request -> Write flow. But I don't see the file saved in my local after I called the API. I have hardcoded Bearer token in the header and raw parameters in body, everything looks good. It doesn't show any error but when I tried to debug it and I'm seeing output and payload both are empty. I'm able to download the gz file with Postman. Am I in the right direction? I saw someone was using outbound endpoint but it is not showing in Mule 4.

Is there any way I can see what the external API returned(Success or failed)? And the content? Please advise.

Many thanks.

Regards,
Richard

Update 1:

[Mule Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZnnm.png)
[DEBUG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo1sI.png)

Added the Flow and the Debugging message. I have simplified the flow and just tried to make the POST rest call with Bearer token. It should return a json response. But still getting an empty response. Do we know what's that java.util.LinkedHashMap thing? Thanks.

Update 2:

[Request Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9BLJ.png)
[Request Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV7FJ.png)

XML Configuration:
[XML Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt36q.jpg)

Comment: Hi @Richard. You are asking a completely abstract question with no real technical details. You should provide steps to reproduce including code, configurations, etc for a minimum example, data for the request, the Postman request for comparison, etc. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on how to create a good question for Stackoverflow. If the API returns a file, why do you expect it in your filesystem? That would be a function of the client, not of an HTTP API, unless it writes files? Again there is no context to understand what is expected.

Comment: Outbound endpoints are a Mule 3 feature that doesn't exist in Mule 4.

Comment: Question doesn't have much details, but as a suggestion you can turn http debug logs to see  if the request that you are sending is same and same for the response. [refer this](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging)

Comment: Sorry pretty new here. Updated with some diagram. Thanks.

Comment: In Stackoverflow you should not use a screenshot for textual information. The other screenshot is not useful. Instead paste the XML as text from the flow and HTTP configuration so we understand what it is doing.

Comment: I'm not able to post images due to the low reputation.

Comment: @Richard what aled meant was to add XML as text. So that the readers can easily copy that and suggest changes

Comment: I see. Got it. Actually, I just make it works now. I will try to do what you and aled said. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add loggers to the application to trace the execution.

You could also enable HTTP wire logging to print requests/responses in the log too. To enable it you have to set the package `org.mule.service.http.impl.service.HttpMessageLogger` to `DEBUG` in the log4j2.xml or in the Runtime Manager console. Detailed instructions available at this [KB article](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging).

Comment: yes I did add that.